# Why does p{Punct} regex leave commas in this example

Tags: java

I need regex to seperate words in lines, here is what I have

```
 public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
countWords(List.of("Some random stuff, another stuff, words in quotes „Example“, Oops!"));

    }
    public static void countWords(List<String> lines) {
        lines.
                stream().map(line -> line.split("[\\\\p{Punct}«»\\s\\d„“…)–]+")).forEach(e -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e)));
 }
    }
```

But the result is

> [Some, ra, dom, s, ff,, a, o, her, s, ff,, words, i, q, o, es, Exam,
> le, ,, Oo, s!]

As you can see we have words split up, extra commas and exclamation mark left ( I thought p{Punct} includes exclamation marks )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unescaping the Java string literal `"\\\\p{Punct}"`, we get:

```
\\p{Punct}
```

In a character class, this is understood as a backslash character, and the characters `p`, `{`, `P`, `u`, `n`, `c`, `t`, `}`, clearly not what you want.

You have added an extra backslash in the regex. Just like `\d` or `\s`, `\p{XXX}` only needs one backslash as the prefix, even when it is used in a character class. So you should remove two backslashes from your Java string literal:

```
"[\\p{Punct}«»\\s\\d„“…)–]+"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish, but the output matches your code.
Your regex matches the occurrences of any of the following: \, p, {, P, u, n, c, t, }, «, », any whitespace, any digit, „, “, …, ), –.

Thus your line is split at a lot of places. The extra commas are because of how `toString` of `Arrays` is implemented.

Here is a helpful resource to check what your regex is actually matching: https://regex101.com/r/bHP5lu/1